# Program crashes after entering "|" to be put in vectors. [Basic]

Tags: c++

this program runs correctly on the output shown by our teachers but it doesnt work if i put 1 2 3 4 5 6 |
or any numbers.

```
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"

int main()
{
    cout << "Enter a series of double values, which represent the distance between two cities\n"
            "(followed by '|' or a another non double/integer character):\n";

    vector<double> distances; // city distances
    for (double distance; cin >> distance; ) // read into distance
        distances.push_back(distance);  // put distance into vector


    // compute total distance:
    double sum {0.0};
    for (double distance : distances)
        sum += distance;
    cout << "Total distance: " << sum << '\n';

    // compute smallest and largest distance:
    sort(distances); // sort distances
    cout << "Smallest distance: " << distances[0] << '\n'
         << "Largest distance: " << distances[distances.size()-1] << '\n';
         
         
    cout << "The mean distance between two cities is: " << sum/distances.size() << '\n';
    keep_window_open();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesnt work" exactly? What is actually happening that you are not expecting? The only problem I see in this code is not checking if `distances.empty()` is true after the 1st loop is done. If `distances` were empty, then `distances[0]`, `distances[distances.size()-1]`, and `sum/distances.size()` would all exhibit *undefined behavior*.

Comment: please show a [mre] with input, expected and actual output

Comment: Answer i expect is Enter a series of temperatures to get the median (followed by '|' or a another non double/integer character):
1 2 3 4 5 |
Average temperature: 3
Median temperature: 3

Comment: Temperatures? Your code uses "distances". Is it the right code? Also, what is your `sort`? If you want `std::sort`, then you need `sort(distances.begin(), distances.end());`.

Answer (score 0):

I converted your code to something "more standard".

Please see:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Enter a series of double values, which represent the distance between two cities\n"
        "(followed by '|' or a another non double/integer character):\n";

    std::vector<double> distances; // city distances
    for (double distance; std::cin >> distance; ) // read into distance
        distances.push_back(distance);  // put distance into vector


    // compute total distance:
    double sum{ 0.0 };
    for (double distance : distances)
        sum += distance;
    std::cout << "Total distance: " << sum << '\n';

    // compute smallest and largest distance:
    std::ranges::sort(distances); // sort distances
    std::cout << "Smallest distance: " << distances[0] << '\n'
        << "Largest distance: " << distances[distances.size() - 1] << '\n';


    std::cout << "The mean distance between two cities is: " << sum / distances.size() << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

It works as expected. But it needs C++20 and the usage of the right namespace qualifier for the function.

It is alwaysbad to use some nonesense like `#include "std_lib_facilities.h"`. Please use always qualified names instead of `using namespace . . .`